# How do i get file_get_contents to work in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

Im using geoplugin.com to display content based on users location
the codex is set up like this:

```
$geoplugin  = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?      ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
```

This works on my dev site but not on my live site. I tried to use wp_remote_get but couldnt get it to set up properly. Any ideas on why this would work on one site and not another?

Comment: The reason might be that the ini-file parameter allow_url_fopen is set to different values on the two servers.

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to pass user input (eg. input you don't *know*) into `unserialize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue   ::

```
   function get_client_ip_env() {  
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }

    $geoplugin  = maybe_unserialize( wp_remote_fopen('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . get_client_ip_env()) );
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `file_get_contents()` isn't active in your server. Instead, use the `wp_remote_get()`.

*Note* `wp_remote_get()` is among the family of WordPress [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) specifically used for sending GET requests.

The advantage of `wp_remote_get()` over `file_get_contents()` and other PHP stream/transport function is - The WordPress HTTP API was created to standardize a single API that handled everything with regards to HTTP as simply as possible. The HTTP API supports various PHP HTTP transports or implementations to cater for different hosting environments and configurations.

In a nutshell, if `file_get_contents()` isn't enabled, `wp_remote_get()` will use cURL if available, if not, it find and uses any available HTTP transport.

Comment: @tcollins Mark my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: how do i make it active and once its active can i just use it like this   $geoplugin  = unserialize( wp_remote_get('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?      ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

Comment: @Tcollins yes. that code should work.

Don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: @Tcollins you didnt include **http** to the url.

Do this:

`wp_remote_get('http://geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Acept my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: nope that doesn't work

Comment: If it doesn't work, check your code.

The HTTP API family functions are already loaded in WordPress.

See this tutorial for more information http://www.sitepoint.com/the-wordpress-http-api/